# Using QGIS Icons in Private Projects

Tags: qgis, license

I am looking at a software development project where we will make the software open source.  The GUI will have icons, and I like the look and feel of some of the icons on QGIS 2.0.  Are there any licensing restrictions or issues with using icons from the QGIS project in other software development projects?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert's original icons are under a Creative Commons license: http://robert.szczepanek.pl/gis-icons-0.1/#request but for QGIS 2.0 a lot of icons have been reworked.

Comment: Is the Creative Commons license associated to QGIS 2.0?  Or do I need to contact the creator of the icons?  If so, how do I do that?  The icons I am interested in are the Add Vector Layer, Add Raster Layer, and Add PostGIS Layer

Comment: CC is not assoicated with QGIS.  If you read the provided link, it says: `GIS icons by Robert Szczepanek is licensed under a Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported License. Feel free to use it in any GIS software or for other purposes. I only ask you to let me know about that and to include licence.txt file in your work.`  See the link to the license restrictions (or lack thereof) [here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or more about Creative Commons [here](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/).